# Plywoods subfloors

Tags: subfloor

Hi I recently had water damaged in the kitchen throughout the living room and guest room and bathroom so I hired a non licensed contractor to take out the old plywood and replace with all new plywood. Then I decided to have tiles done all over the whole house.
First . we have hardibacker over the plywood and then porcelain tile on top throughout the whole house now I am very concerned if the plywood even have spacing .
If the plywood has no spacing what's going to happen throughout the whole house?

Someone please help answer the questions.
 Thank you very much
Gina

Comment: I use toung and grove plywood the plywood is butted tight and screwed in place with no spaces. Are you saying you person left spaces or you think there should be some?

Comment: Should there be space next to the wall?

Comment: Should there be space next to the wall? Could the structure of the house be damages if there no space when the plywoods expanded? Can the tile be buckle up since there's no space for the plywoods to expands?

Comment: I have never spaced plywood in any of the homes I built or in my personal residence. I usually make sure the sheets are tight and underlayment for tile usually cement board is also tight and fill the seams with quick set if there are gaps there is less support and the screws will need to be put in at an angle to hold well and not squeak. I make sure the plywood and and underlayment seams are not on the same line and have not had any problems with tile even 12" square. Usually the plywood decking is under the walls you can put tile on plywood but cement board or hardi backer is better no spaces

Comment: Hello Ed Beal,  thank you very much for answering my questions.  Now I don't have to worry too much about the floor.